# delete non important characters from command output

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk

the version command in my Linux machines display the following output

```
version


Red.Hat.OS. release..........5.5
APP.Release.............4.2.0.0-02
```

how to remove the middle "**.**" dot character without to remove them from the parameters as the following:

```
 version | .......


 Red.Hat.OS. release          5.5
 APP.Release version         4.2.0.0-02
```

- remark in parameter between the character could be only one dot character

Comment: `version |tr -d .`

Comment: `version | sed 's/\.\{2,\}/\t/'`

Comment: @Costas's suggestion does what you want. Something different - but possibly still useful - could be done w/ `tr` as well. You can `-s`queeze *and* `-d`elete two different sets of characters the same time. So `version|tr -sd \  .` prints `Red.Hat.OS.release.5.5\nAPP.Release.4.2.0.0-02\n`. So it  would retain all of the relevant dot separators, but would remove all intervening space at the same time.

Comment: via `awk`, which allows a better space between key and value:  `version |awk -F '\.\.+' '{printf "%-24s%s\n", $1, $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

- replace the first occurence of >1 `.` by TAB: `sed 's/\.\.\+/\t/'`
- replace all occurences of >1 `.` by TAB:`sed 's/\.\.\+/\t/g'` / `awk -F"[.][.]+" -vOFS="\t" '($1=$1)||1'`
- replace the first occurence of >1 `.` followed by a digit by TAB: `sed 's/\.\.\+\([[:digit:]]\)/\t\1/'`
- replace all occurences of >1 `.` followed by a digit by TAB: `sed 's/\.\.\+\([[:digit:]]\)/\t\1/g'` / `gawk -vRS="[.][.]+[[:digit:]]" '(ORS=(RT?"\t"substr(RT,length(RT)):""))||1'`

All those commands will return your desired output for the input given.

Feel free to ask for explanations and/or adjustments.